# problemas com IF e ELSE

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu gostaria de saber como voltar o programa para o primeiro `if` ou `elif` caso a resposta do usuário não se encaixe na pergunta sobre a distância.

Eu coloquei um `else` com um `print("responda sim ou não")` e caso a resposta não seja `s | n` o programa é finalizado. Mas eu quero que ele pergunte a distância de novo até o usuário responder corretamente.

```
nome = input("Qual é o seu nome? \n")

pergunta = (input("{}, você sabe a distância?\n ".lower().format(nome)))

if pergunta.startswith('s'):

    distancia = float(input("qual é a distância?\n"))

    aproveitamento = float(input('{}, quantos quilometros seu carro faz por litro? \n'.format(nome)))

    precogas = int(input('{}, qual é o preço da gasolina atualmente?\n'.format(nome)))

    consumo = distancia / aproveitamento

    print("Foram gastos ", consumo, " litros de combustível.")

    custo = consumo * precogas

    print("E você vai gastar", custo, "reais")

elif pergunta.startswith('n'):

    tempohoras = float(input("{}, digite o tempo gasto na viagem (Apenas quantas horas): \n".format(nome)))

    tempominutos = float(input("{}, e quantos minutos? \n".format(nome)))

    velocidade = float(input('{}, digite agora a velocidade média durante a viagem:\n'.format(nome)))

    aproveitamento = float(input('{}, quantos quilometros seu carro faz por litro? \n'.format(nome)))

    precogas = float(input('{}, qual é o preço da gasolina atualmente?\n'.format(nome)))

    consumo = (velocidade * (tempohoras + (tempominutos / 60))) / aproveitamento

    print("Foram gastos ", consumo, " litros de combustível.")

    custo = consumo * precogas

    distancia = velocidade * (tempohoras + (tempominutos / 60))

    print("E você vai gastar", custo, "reais")

    print("A distância percorrida foi de ", distancia, "quilometros.")

else:
    print ("responda sim ou não")
```

Comment: A primeira coisa aqui seria você [edit] e reduzir o código a um [mcve] (esse monte de input é irrelevante para o problema, reduza o código só ao que importa). Aproveite para usar o botão `{ }` da barra de formatação ou control/comand k para formatar o bloco de código.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você colocar seu código dentro de um bloco `while` passando alguma instrução ou então utilizando o `break` para sair do bloco e prosseguir com o código. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
nome = input("Qual é o seu nome? \n")

while True:

    pergunta = input("{}, você sabe a distância?\n ".lower().format(nome))

    if not pergunta[0] in "sn": 
        print("Responda sim ou não.")
    else: 
        break

# Resto do código ...
```

O que o `while` faz é repetir um bloco de código enquanto uma condição for verdadeira. Veja a sintaxe dele abaixo:

```
while condição:      
    # Código...
```

No exemplo acima, ele repete o código pedindo uma resposta válida ao usuário, e se a resposta for correta, ele para a execução do `while` com a declaração `break`.

Comment: Qual o motivo da negativo já que o algorítimo  atende os requisitos da pergunta?

Comment: Isso está acontecendo muito nessa semana. Tem algum engraçadinho trollando aqui no site ;p

Comment: Calma, não julgue precipitadamente, as vezes é o AP que não entendeu como encaixar o algorítimo no seu código.